# Problem with having available resources in Simpy

Tags: python, simpy

I'm attempting to write a program to simulate callers joining a network for a simulated amount of time, which take up a "Channel" resource on the network, using Simpy. I am having an issue where it doesn't seem that the resource is ever made available, and am likely missing something due to being a novice with this package. Here is the code:

`

```
class Network(object):
    def __init__(self, env, num_channels):
        self.env = env
        self.channel = simpy.Resource(env, num_channels)

    def join_channel(self, caller):
        yield self.env.timeout(np.random.lognormal(1, .25))  # in Seconds. 

def start_call(env, caller, network): # AKA 'go_to_movies' in tutorial
    with network.channel.request() as request:          # Generates a request to use a channel
        yield request                                   # caller waits for a channel, if none available. 
        yield env.process(network.join_channel(caller)) # Caller joins a channel for specified time


def run_network(env, num_channels):
    network = Network(env, num_channels)

    for caller in range(1):
        env.process(start_call(env, caller, network))
        print(network.channel.count)

    call_start_times = (np.random.uniform(0, 60, 600)).astype(int) # Integer Array of call start times, 60 steps                                                                
    start_time_occurences = []  # index 0 acts as number of callers to initialize NW with

    # Counts occurences of each call start minute in call_start_times[] distribution  
    for j in range(60): 
        count = np.count_nonzero(call_start_times == j)
        start_time_occurences.append(count)

    # Iterates through number of indexes in start_time_occurences, 
    # starting the corresponding amount of callers for each minute 
    for i in range(len(start_time_occurences)):

        # Print Caller info and Channel availability 
        if i == 0:
            print("Initializing Network with " + str(start_time_occurences[i]) + " callers")
            print(f'{network.channel.count} of {network.channel.capacity} channels are available')
        else:
            print(str(start_time_occurences[i]) + " callers just began a call at minute " + str(i))
            print(f'{network.channel.count} of {network.channel.capacity} channels are available')

        
        for caller in range(start_time_occurences[i]):
            if network.channel.count == 0:
                print("All channels full. Dropping call")
            else:
                env.process(start_call(env, caller, network))

    yield env.timeout(1)           # in minutes, Wait before generating a new caller


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Setup
    random.seed(42)
    num_channels = 41

    # Run the network
    env = simpy.Environment()
    env.process(run_network(env, num_channels))
    env.run(until=100)
```

`

I have tried assigning the resource in different parts of the code, but the channel resource, although instantiated to 41 channels, will always output that there are 0 channels (shown using 'network.channel.count').

I'm likely missing something fundamental, so thanks for the help and patience!

Comment: I thought network.channel.count would be the number of resources in use.  So network.channel.count == 0 would mean no resource are being used and all channels are available.  count is the number of users that have a resource, not the count of available resources.

Comment: also, you yield timeout at the bottom of your code is not inside the for loop, should it be?